# How to display time series data in Grafana based on Loki log query

Tags: logging, time-series, visualization, grafana, grafana-loki

In Grafana Cloud, I have a Loki data source with many log lines in an arbitrary format. Let's say they're in the form of: `MyValue1: 0.1, MyValue2: 0.3`. I want to show the values of `MyValue1` and `MyValue2` on a time-series graph, with each value shown at the corresponding line's time (the time is saved in Loki when the line is received).

To achieve this, I extract the values as labels using a regex log parser, in this case the regex is `MyValue1: (?P<myval1>\d+\.*\d*), MyValue2: (?P<myval2>\d+\.*\d*)`. It works, and the labels `myval1` and `myval2` are added to each line.

I create a Time Series visualizer with the Data Source set to the logs. Without any transformations, in "Table View" mode, a table is shown, with each line having a `time` column, and a `labels` column with i.e. `{ "myval1": "0.1", "myval2": "0.3" }`. After adding an "Extact Fields" transformation with "Source" set to "labels", the table is tranformed to have two new string-type columns, `"myval1"` and `"myval2"`, with correct values.

I am struggling in the next step, however. I assume the string values need to be converted to number values, the graph needs to be setup to show those values at their correspodning times. However, adding a seemingly-correct "Convert Field Type" transformation results in the entire table disappearing.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I show these table values on a graph?

**Note: I am using Grafana Cloud and its online GUI, not self-hosted Grafana and/or CLI.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution I found for graphing 2 values on one line:

If your log file looks like this

```
MyValue1: 0.1, MyValue2: 0.3
MyValue1: 0.14, MyValue2: 0.34
MyValue1: 0.24, MyValue2: 0.39
```

you can get a time series graph of first value using the following

```bash
max_over_time({filename="/var/tmp/mylogs/mylog.log"} |= ``
| pattern "MyValue1: <value1>, MyValue2: <_>"
| unwrap value1 [1m])
```

then in a separate query in the same gui, add a variation for 2nd value:

```bash
max_over_time({filename="/var/tmp/mylogs/mylog.log"} |= ``
| pattern "MyValue1: <_>, MyValue2: <value2>"
| unwrap value2 [1m])
```

You can even add a 3rd query to modify the values:

```bash
# multiply the value by 0.001
max_over_time({filename="/var/tmp/mylogs/mylog.log"} |= ``
| pattern "MyValue1: <_>, MyValue2: <value2>"
| label_format value2="{{mulf .value2 .001}}"
| unwrap value2 [1m])
```

or create an entirely new field

```bash
# graphs the new 'product' field
max_over_time({filename="/var/tmp/myfiles/afile.log"} |= ``
| pattern "MyValue1: <t1>, MyValue2: <t2>"
| line_format "product={{mulf .t1 .t2}}"
| logfmt
| line_format "final_product={{mulf .product .t2}}"
| logfmt
| unwrap final_product
| __error__ = ""[$__interval]) by (time)
```

Comment: Thank you! Quite an understandable solution.